# Insert node in a single link list while the header pointer position is unknown in C

Tags: c, pointers

Actually, we have a two pointers in a single link list. The head pointer position is unknown. The second pointer is known.
For example, Consider this is a list 1->2->3->4->5. The second pointer is pointing the element 2. If we try to insert the node at position 2 between node1 and 2, how the insertion take place?. Is it possible to insert the node as same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that the structure of your node is

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}
```

and the pointer pointing to the element 2 is called *ptr*. If you want to insert a node exactly at the point where ptr points, you need to insert one more pointer at the *previous* node of ptr. This is because after allocating memory for your new node (suppose that the allocation returns a pointer to the new node called "new"), you need to make the pointer "next" of your previous node to point to the pointer "new" of your new node.

However, by not knowing where your header is, you cannot access the previous node of ptr, as the list is single linked and the first node you have access to is the node pointed by ptr. You have no way to find all the previous nodes of the one pointed by ptr.

**As a conclusion**, you should always know where your Header pointer points. It is used as a reference to the list so that you can access it (especially in a single linked list where you cannot go backwards to the previous node).

Answer (score 0):

Insertion in single link list before known link is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert a node in between nodes 1 and 2 in this case. Since it's a single linked list, you have no information about node 1. You can't traverse back. 
You can insert a node between nodes 2 and 3 though.